# Can't build my android project after move it to another computer

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I can't build my android project in react native project, i just used this project in my old computer and it built fine, but after i clone it from my new macbook i get error.

I tried to delete the cache folder and it didn't help.

The error that i get:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings remapped class cache for espedq8f7vbnwrshulq11juyl (/Users/(UserName)/.gradle/caches/5.0/scripts-remapped/settings_3tlaqtt0fziq08p73u9gmyutn/espedq8f7vbnwrshulq11juyl/settingsa9190c3ddc71e1450eb3f3e7bc6a334f).

- Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/(UserName)/Desktop/MyApp/friendsapp/client/android/settings.gradl' (/Users/(UserName)/.gradle/caches/5.0/scripts/espedq8f7vbnwrshulq11juyl/settings/settingsa9190c3ddc71e1450eb3f3e7bc6a334f).
- BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes i found the answer!
I just clicked in android studio, FILE -> sync project with gradle files .
It did the magic !

### Edit

Help me so many times for building:

1. yarn add jetifier
2. yarn run jetify
3. rebuild project in android studio

Answer (score 1):

To clear Android Studio's cache and bring it out of its state of confusion, select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button.
You should invalidate caches from android studio not deleting cache folder directly.